# How to add second variable to a variable in a dropdown using PHP?

Tags: php

I have an HTML select element created in PHP.  I want to add $car (a second variable) with the $person_name.  So it should $car and $person_name. how can i do it to the snippet below:

```
        echo "<option value=\"".$person_id."\">".$person_name."</option>";
```

Comment: You want $car to be part of what DISPLAYS in the drop down, or part of the VALUE that is submitted if it is selected?

Comment: What is a php dropdown? Did you simply want to echo another line?

Comment: Both the value and the display. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is giving you trouble from what you've tried?

Comment: You'll have a harder time handling the submitted value if you have more than one value... Maybe you should be using 2 separate drop downs, one for car one for person, so you can properly get both elements on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "<option value=\"".$person_id."\">" . $car . " - " . $person_name."</option>";
```

This will cause the display value in the drop-down to show (if $car = "Chevy" and $person_name = "Fosco"): "Chevy - Fosco"

Comment: how can i add i to the value too?

Comment: @KPO the same way...   `value=\"" . $person_id . "/" . $car . "\"` and then you can split() the value by `/` on the server side to get both individually.

Answer (score 1):

I think you means add another variable.

Example 1:

```
 echo "<option value=\"".$person_id."\">".$person_name.$car."</option>";
```

Example 2:

```
 echo "<option value=\"".$person_id."\">".$person_name.' '.$car."</option>";
```

Comment: Why would you want two options with the same value? Not your fault, it's a terribly phrased question.

Comment: Ahh OK, I need to just stay away from these kind of vague questions, where the folks trying to help have to guess everything the OP wants.

Comment: You have an error in your first echo. You are missing the period after $car.

Comment: I just want to be able to add $person_id and $car to both the values and display..

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<option value='$person_id $car'>$person_name $car</option>";
```